# Is there a way to access the background calculation & data in a .exe coded in fortran 30+ years ago?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, unpacking, executable

The company I work for has an ancient (circa 1989-1992) program coded in Fortran that is used for sizing and selecting some of our products. We are going through a modernization project with the goal of creating a cloud-based program to replace it. We don't have any documentation or access to the source material of the existing program. The CD sleeve says "for Win 95/98" and not much else.

The problem is that over time the knowledge to perform some of the calculations has left the business through retirements and people moving on. When we ask the few long-timers that remain, they can only point to the program and say "we don't know how to do it, we just use the program." There wasn't git back then...

Anyway, is there a way to go from the .exe backwards and see how the program was built and what data/equations are in it? I've done some research and it seems that the compiler were flatten much of the information and even if it were accessible, it might not be legible.

Is there any way to "crack" open the program and extract the data/equations we need? I have the program on a CD-rom and we have it for download on our website.

Comment: They way is to RE the program. You might not get the original code, but given enough time you should get the original behavior.